# ClassNotFoundException for compile scope in maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have included a third party `tomcat jar` in my `pom.xml` with a `compile` default scope. It runs fine on my machine with `Eclipse`. But when I run it on another server. It gives `ClassNotFoundException` while initializing a bean class in xml file. Aren't the `compile` scoped jar available at `runtime` as well?

Comment: Yes but other things can impact it too. You should to include an actual MRE if you expect actual help  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that just building a jar will not include any dependencies. This is the desired behaviour for libraries.

If you want a runnable jar, you need to use the maven assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin.